# Are the infinity norm and the the induced norm equivalent in $l^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider the function $||\cdot||_\infty:l^2\to[0,\infty)$ given by

$$||(a_n)||_\infty = \sup\{|a_n|:n\ge 1\}.$$

So I want to know if this norm is equivalent to:

$$||(a_n)||=\sqrt{\sum |a_n|^2}$$

This is because I have been trying to prove (supposing they are equivalent) that:

$$c||(a_n)||<||(a_n)||_\infty<C||(a_n)||$$

I chose this way because I think this is the easiest way, the reason is that I found very tricky to prove $c||(a_n)||_\infty<||(a_n)||<C||(a_n)||_\infty$. In this case we will have that:

$$||(a_n)||=\sqrt{\sum |a_n|^2} <\sqrt{\sum ||a_n||_\infty^2}$$

But the thing is that I can't figure out how to attached those inequalities, I was trying to use the partial sums, but I think is the same problem.

Can someone help me to prove or disprove this assertion please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Only one side of the inequality holds. The other side holds on $\mathbb{R}^N$ with a constant that blows up as $N\to \infty$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more in this please ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can prove the following inequality: 
$$\max\left\{ \lvert a_n\rvert\, :\, n=1\ldots N\right\} 
\le \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^2}\le 
\sqrt{N}\max\left\{\lvert a_n\rvert\, :\, n=1\ldots N\right\}.$$

Comment: Ok, just give me a second, and If I get stuck, can I let you know ?

Comment: Hello @GiuseppeNegro , I am back, but I don't see the lower bound :(, thanks

Comment: And other thing, the $max$ should be $sup$ right?

Comment: The sup of a finite set is always a max. And the inequality is trivial: assume that the maximum is attained on $a_m$ and note that $\lvert a_m\rvert \le \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^2}$.

Comment: jajajaj, right :) I have realize that part, but does this is sufficient to prove the non-equivalence between that norms? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

they are not equivalent : you should consider $$a_{n,p} = \left\{1 \; if \;n < p\;,\; 1/n \;if \;n \ge p \right\}$$
For any p $(a_{n,p})_n$ is $l_2$ but there is a p to have a contradiction

Comment: How do you know is $l^2$?

Comment: because $1/n$ is $l_2$, and there is only a finite number of terms different

Comment: Ok , just give me time to get the idea, an if I get stuck , can I let you know ?

Comment: Yes let me know if you get stuck

Comment: Really no need for the $1/n$ terms.

Comment: @zhw yes 0 is enough but $1/n$ was the first thing I thought to

Comment: sorry, but I don't see how this is $l^2$, thanks in advance (I am assuming that $n \in \mathbb{N}$)

Comment: this $$a_{n,p} = \left\{1\; if\; n <p\;, \; 0\; if\; n \ge p \right\}$$ works too

Comment: for every integer p , $\|(a_ {n,p})_n\|_\infty =1 \;,\; \|(a_ {n,p})_n\|=\sqrt{p-1}$ so there exists a p that makes a contraction with the equivalence