# Prove or disprove that this space is complete

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the function $||\cdot||_\infty:l^2\to[0,\infty)$ given by

$$||(a_n)||_\infty = \sup\{|a_n|:n\ge 1\}.$$

so I want to figure out if $ (l^2,||\cdot||_\infty)$ is complete. Then I was wondering that the sequence given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522854/are-the-infinity-norm-and-the-the-induced-norm-equivalent-in-l2) could be a good counter example, but I am not sure about it.

Then my question is, Can someone help me to prove or disprove the assertion please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Using @JohnMa's answer we have that each of the $a_n \in l^2$ since there are only finite terms that are non-zero, then if we pick $a_n,a_m$ for $n>m$ we get

$$||a_n-a_m||_\infty =||(\frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}},\ldots,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})||_\infty=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}} \to 0$$

so the sequence of sequences $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy, but I am a little bit stuck with the convergence part, one thing I have notice is that $||a_n||_\infty=1$ for all $n$ but I don't know how to use that.

Comment: I think you can guess (and show) the limit. Is that limit an element of $\ell^2$?

Comment: Ok, let me think a little bit :), just a second please :)

Comment: So, using @skyking's result that $a$ is not in $l^2$ right? becuase the series of $1/n$ doesn't converge

Comment: Yes, perfect ${}{}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot,but, Can you help me with this one please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523342/how-to-prove-the-following-assertion-about-hilbert-spaces Thanks in advance :) I mean Is @GiussepesNegro's assertion right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$a_n = \left( 1, \frac 1{\sqrt 2}, \frac 1{\sqrt 3}, \cdots, \frac{1}{\sqrt n}, 0 ,0 ,\cdots \right)$$

Comment: Right,but the counter example should be a sequence of sequences right?

Comment: Yes, @user162343 : we have $a_1 = (1,0,0,\cdots)$, $a_2 = (1, \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}, 0, 0, \cdots )$

Comment: Oh jajajaaj, right, so let me check that, and if I get stuck, Can I let you know?

Comment: @user162343 : Great! Just leave a comment here if you need help.

Comment: But you have $||a_n-a||_{\infty}=1/\sqrt{n+1}$ where $a=(1,1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt3,...)$ so the sequence is convergent.

Comment: @JohnMa You're correct, I missed that detail.

Comment: I have edited my post :)